# Could I keep buildings heated during multi week long hibernation?

Tags: magic, survival, seasons, daily-life

In the world of a story I'm writing, there is not normal night and day, nor are there seasons. Instead, the world is governed by magical lights, which occur in several week cycles - the light Dawn has an effect similar to spring, awakening everything in the world, filling it with energy, Toil is similar to summer, and provides endurance, Dusk is self explanatory - but Night has no magical sun, it is the absence of magic, and with no energy, it makes everyone very tired, and both people and animals hibernate for the several week duration.

Sticking with the theme, Night is a cold bitter winter, but obviously, to keep people alive, the buildings need to be kept warm. So my question is, would people be able to reasonably keep their homes warm with preindustrial technology, waking up every so often to build back up a fire? Or would I have to turn to magical means to modify the situation or make it possible?

Comment: I feel one incorrect assumption is making this incredibly difficult. You don't need to have buildings heated. You need the people heated. This already greatly simplifies the question. We can see people sleeping in sleeping bags and tiny tents on a rock wall with -20°C. To make your question even easier is hibernation. Many (all?) hot blooded creatures reduce their metabolism and temperature drastically. This also lowers any heat requirements of buildings or sleeping bags.

Comment: This has me remembering *[The Second Chronicles of Thomas Covenant the Unbeliever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Thomas_Covenant)* series. It used a similar story mechanic.

Answer (score 3):

You can harvest the energy available during the Toil and store it somewhere which then releases it when Night comes.

Think of something like heating up a large amount of water and then using it to warm the colder air. Or making the buildings with thick stone walls, which take very long to heat up and cool down, so that the "heat wave" from Toil reaches the inside during Night.

I think this is preferrable to have a sleepy and not so energetic someone pay attention to a fire which can potentially kill everybody should it become not manageable anymore.

Comment: I feel like this is probably the best solution I've come to - that being, living things absorb the energy of the different lights, so cutting down trees during Toil would result in slow burning wood.

Answer (score 3):

If it's to be done with pre-industrial technology then people would mostly have to manually put in the work.

They should gather in large groups, in a building specifically designed for this. Mostly because tending to one large heat source is much easier than one per household. But also, one heat source could be managed by a dedicated team, rather than the head of each household. Look into the [Roman hypocaust buildings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypocaust#:%7E:text=Hypocausts%20were%20used%20for%20heating,villas%2C%20throughout%20the%20Roman%20Empire.), some of the earliest forms of central heating. Such a building could be community-run, or even funded by the government. A small team of people would keep the heat going for the duration, and a few weeks isn't too long for a heated and well-insulated building to survive. Especially not with a well stocked and efficiently run fire. It could even be built underground for extra heat retention.

Comment: This is an interesting idea. I wonder if perhaps it could be done where this village has their fireplaces accessible outside at night, so that a group of people employed by the village can maintain the fires, or all the fires connected somehow.

Answer (score 3):

**I give you *Japanese Macaques* (snow monkeys) and their ingenious use of hot springs**

[image]
*Image courtesy [Japan-Guide.com](https://www.japan-guide.com/e/e6028.html).*

> Scientists have long believed that this behavior can be chalked up to a logical explanation: the monkeys are cold, and dipping in the hot springs helps them keep warm during frigid winters in northern Japan. [But,] working on the assumption that the monkeys use hot springs to keep warm, the Kyoto University team tested the animals’ feces for levels of glucocorticoids, a metabolite that is linked to biological stress.... Researchers tracked 12 adult females during the spring birth season (from April to June) and the winter mating season (from October to December). The results of their study, published recently in the journal Primate, showed that the snow monkeys used the hot springs more frequently during the winter. The team also found that the in the colder months, the macaques had lower levels of fecal glucocorticoids during weeks that they bathed, compared to weeks they did not. ([Source](https://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/chilling-out-hot-springs-may-help-japans-snow-monkeys-reduce-stress-180968686/))

**Your solution: divert a hot spring through the hibernation chamber**

Personally, I think that soaking in a hot mineral bath during hibernation would be the *echt* of low-stress, high-rejuvination, hibernation. But, if you're not into really, really, *really,* long baths, then just running the hot spring through the enclosure (open, piped, etc.) will bring the heat you're looking for.

Comment: While a very efficient idea, (hot springs are natures thermal vents, and offer heat for free), they are also very localised. I'm only aware of the ones found in Japan, so OP would have to mimic Japans geological and geothermal climate throughout their entire world.

Comment: @Plutian Only in Japan? There are hot springs all across the U.S. with the exception of the highest plateaus. And I can't imagine anything wrong with (a) the OP placing a hot spring anywhere he/she desires (no imaginary world is bound to Real World geophysics) or (b) the people of the OP's world being localized to what hot springs exist. it's the OP's problem to use or not use an idea - not mine to guarantee the idea will fit with any whim of the OP's (or yours...).

Comment: It seems I am incorrect indeed, after some research, I found hot springs are a lot more common than I realised. Also, I did not mean to discount your answer in the slightest, just highlight the geothermal requirements for OP to keep in mind. Although I do stand by the fact that OP would need a LOT more hot springs than currently exist, to keep a sizeable population alive. But you are correct, that is for OP to implement.

Answer (score 2):

I would look to the lifestyles of the Northern Polar region peoples and how they dealt with Winter (when it's pretty much perpetual darkness) - e.g. Tromso in Norway, which had inhabitants going back around 10,000 years

The Sami people, for example, used to sleep on a bed of specially prepared Willow embers to stay warm at night.

Comment: Interesting. This probably won't be how I do it for the main people in my story, but perhaps can be explored as what different groups of people in my world do.